# Foreign Key Column as a covering index

Tags: sql-server

A company I contract for has a legacy set of tables which use soft-deletes and some interesting table structuring.  The joins are PK-->FK relationships, but the issue comes with so many different queries accessing different columns.

The write rate is low, and the read rate is high. So, it would lead me to believe that creating multiple covering indices on the multiple child columns utilized by the queries would not pose a risk on performance as just having a single index.  With disk space aside, what would be the *best* suggestion for just the child table FacilityVisit index (indices).

Here’s a very simplified example (some of the tables have 25 cols queried by different queries):

```
CREATE TABLE Person (
 PersonID INT IDENTITY (1,1) 
,FirstName VARCHAR(100)
,Lastname VARCHAR(100)
CONSTRAINT [PK_Person_PersonID] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (PersonID)
)
GO

CREATE TABLE FacilityVisit (
 FacilityVisitID INT IDENTITY (1,1)
,PersonID INT
,VisitDateTime DATETIME
,SecionVisited INT
,ScoreGiven INT
,[Status] BIT
CONSTRAINT [PK_FacilityVisit_FacilityVisitID] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (FacilityVisitID)
)
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[FacilityVisit]  WITH CHECK 
   ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_FacilityVisit_PersonID] FOREIGN KEY([PersonID])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Person] ([PersonID])
GO

/* Possible logical Indexes for FacilityVisit */

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX FK_FacilityVisit_CIndex1 
     ON FacilityVisit ([PersonID])
--OR
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX FK_FacilityVisit_CIndex2 
     ON FacilityVisit ([PersonID],[VisitDateTime],[Status])

--OR 
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX FK_FacilityVisit_CIndex3 
     ON FacilityVisit ([PersonID],[VisitDateTime],[Status]) 
     INCLUDE (SectionVisited,ScoreGiven)
```

Possible Queries:

```
/* This would best utilzie FK_FacilityVisit_CIndex1 */
SELECT 
 p.FirstName
,P.LastName
FROM Person p
JOIN FacilityVisit fv on fv.PersonID = p.PersonID

/* this would better utilzie FK_FacilityVisit_CIndex2 */
SELECT 
 p.FirstName
,P.LastName
FROM Person p
JOIN FacilityVisit fv on fv.PersonID = p.PersonID
WHERE fv.Status = 1
AND fv.VisitDateTime >= '01/01/2015' AND fv.VisitDateTime <= '12/31/2015'

/* this would best utilzie FK_FacilityVisit_CIndex3 */
SELECT 
 p.Firstname
,p.LastName
,fv.VisitDate
,fv.SectionVisited
,fv.ScoreGiven
FROM Person p
JOIN FacilityVisit fv on fv.PersonID = p.PersonID
WHERE fv.Status = 1
AND fv.VisitDateTime >= '01/01/2015' AND fv.VisitDateTime <= '12/31/2015'
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly remember this, measure twice optimise once... whenever you want to optimise something you must measure it before and after you put in your optimisation, and if it doesn't give a significant enough optimisation, or it makes it slower! undo the optimisation.

Secondly even if you are not adept at reading query execution plans have a look at them for the queries you are running, often SQL server will recommend indexes that it thinks would help, but again measure the change just to make sure. They are also a fantastic way to find out what you should try optimising.

Now of your three index examples, I'd pick the last one with a slight modification:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX FK_FacilityVisit_CIndex3 
 ON FacilityVisit ([PersonID],[Status],[VisitDateTime]) 
 INCLUDE (SectionVisited,ScoreGiven)
```

All of your three possible queries could use this index. By changing the order of the key fields you narrow the search down to a single range within the key meaning it can be searched using an index seek. However if you didn't filter the PersonID then this index is unlikely to be used.

Finally, you want a covering index, you have 2 tables with an inner join, and you are specifying columns: You could create a view and add a covering index to it like this:

```
CREATE PersonFacilityVisit
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS 
SELECT 
     p.PersonID
    ,p.Firstname
    ,p.LastName
    ,fv.FacilityVisitID
    ,fv.VisitDateTime
    ,fv.SecionVisited
    ,fv.ScoreGiven
FROM dbo.Person p
JOIN dbo.FacilityVisit fv on fv.PersonID = p.PersonID
WHERE Status = 1
GO

CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX PK_PersonVisit_View
    ON PersonFacilityVisit (PersonID, FacilityVisitID)

CREATE INDEX IX_PersonVisit_View 
     ON PersonFacilityVisit ([VisitDateTime],[PersonID]) 
     INCLUDE (Firstname,LastName,SecionVisited,ScoreGiven)
```

You can read more about creating indexed views [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd171921(v=sql.100).aspx).